# How to check the disk partitions usage of juniper device?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos

In this article : https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB33032&cat=ROUTER_PRODUCTS&actp=LIST

```
root@PE1:/var/home/labroot # gpart show -p
=>      34  62533229    ada0  GPT  (30G)
          34         6          - free -  (3.0K)
          40        56  ada0p1  freebsd-boot  (28K)
          96  16777209  ada0p3  freebsd-swap  (8.0G)
         16777305         7          - free -  (3.5K)
         16777312  45755937  ada0p2  freebsd-ufs  (22G)
          62533249        14          - free -  (7.0K)
 
=>     34  7980269    ada1  GPT  (3.8G)
         34        6          - free -  (3.0K)
         40       56  ada1p1  freebsd-boot  (28K)
         96  7980193  ada1p2  freebsd-ufs  (3.8G)
         7980289       14          - free -  (7.0K)
 
Observe the SSD, which is 30G and partitioned as:

swap: 8GB
junos: 22G
The CF is 3.8G and partitioned as:

oam: 3.8G
```

we can know disk allocation is below:
swap: 8GB
junos: 22G
oam: 3.8G

but how can I know the usage percentage of them?

---

The device is MX-serias.

Comment: The simplest answer: it's FreeBSD, run `df``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partition table shows the partition level. Usage within a partition is up to the file system.

The article you've linked to suggests (pre Junos OS 15.1 / FreeBSD 6.1):

```
show system storage | match "/dev/ad0s1a|/dev/ad1s1f"
```

or (Junos OS 15.1+ / FreeBSD 10):

```
show system storage | match "/dev/gpt/junos"
```

On JunOS OS 15.1+, the Compact Flash card isn't mounted and cannot be inspected this way.